# How to display a nested list in Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working with Jasper Reports, and I have a list of items, that in some cases could have a list per each item.

I'm using Jaspers' Table element to display the table, but I can't figure out how to display the nested list.

**JasperReport Code:**

```
<subDataset name="LineItems">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="rangeItem.rangeId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="rangeItem.name.defaultString" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="itemQuantity.quantity" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="isGroupedItems" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <field name="isSingleItem" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
</subDataset>

<field name="invoiceLineList" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
.
.
.
<jr:table>
    <datasetRun subDataset="LineItems">
        <dataSourceExpression>
            <![CDATA[$F{invoiceLineList}]]>
        </dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    <jr:column>
      .....
    </jr:column>
</jr:table>
```

**Passed list "Datasource"**

```
List<ItemLine> itemsList
...
itemsList.flattenSublineItems()

class ItemLine{
    List<InvoiceSubLine> subLineList
    String itemType
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**What is the best element to use in JasperReport to show grouped items within each item (close to the table shown in the bottom)? Or, if the table is suitable, how should I group items within it?**

[image]

Comment: Did you try searching "table group Jasperreports" in Google? [A tutorial on the official page](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-user-guide-v52/working-tables). It is all you really need. I don't think nesting list inside of a table or list is a good idea.

Comment: @Amongalen I worked with reporting tools before "DevExpress and MSReporting", and usually, we have group bands that you only need to pass a sub-dataset for it, which is the nested list in my case. Please, if you can help in this direction, just give me pointers. And yes, I did some google research.

Comment: A pointer is remove the jr:table use a subreport (or directly in main report if only 1 group) to group your data and display the data in normal detail band.